# Madison Island View details and Add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I am new to Magento so please forgive me if my question sounds foolish.
I have the default Madison Island template which was there when i installed magento. I noticed that if you are looking on product list under men/ women section than it shows (View Details) on the listing
[image]
 where as if you look under Accessories it shows (Add to Cart).
[image]

I turned on Template Path Hints to check which file controls the Display ( with google's help)

and the file is

```
frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

So my question is how does the same file show two different displays( View Products and Add to Chart )??

Or is there any thing else that controls such output ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer can be found in the template file, lines 89 to 95:

```
<?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
<?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
    <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The blazer is a configurable product, so you need to specify its options (e.g. size or colour) to add it to your cart. This can be done from the detail page.

The sunglasses are a simple product, and you can add them to your cart directly.

There would be a lot more to say about this, but I hope I answered your question more or less.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer ... i just figured it out some time ago while i was going through every line of the code but I really appreciate your help.  M new to magento so I appreciate all your help. Thanks again.